# How to get frames from video files and process them in real time

Tags: android, video

I'm writing an application to add some effects by editing frames (like moving pixels, removing, adding... not just put effects on it) from video files. Is there a way to get frames and render edited frames to the screen in real time?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @ShivamVerma are there any other ways that not using any additional library?

Comment: Afaik, android doesnt provide any support for frame by frame video manipulation.

Comment: @ShivamVerma is there any workaround?